# Launching AVD from command line stuck on Revoking microphone permissions for Google App

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line, android-emulator

I am running a command to launch AVD, however, when the device launch - stuck on this error.

> Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.

Any Clue on whats going? I'm Using AVD devices API 28

Same Error when running these command:

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_28
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_28
```

> emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but with API 29.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding `-no-audio` to the `emulator` command did the trick.