# Emulator Stuck: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App

Tags: android, permissions, android-emulator, android-permissions

In Android Studio I created an emulator...
`avdmanager create avd --force --name testAvd --abi google_apis_playstore/x86 --package "system-images;android-29;google_apis_playstore;x86"`

and tried to start it...
`emulator -avd testAvd -no-boot-anim -no-snapshot-save -no-audio -no-window -gpu off -debug -all`.

It stucks now at
`emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.`.

Does anybody have an explanation and a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Also, this question is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58206185/launching-avd-from-command-line-stuck-on-revoking-microphone-permissions-for-goo, just in case an answer comes up there that we can adopt here too.

Comment: Using `-no-audio` as per https://forum.katalon.com/t/avd-stuck-on-permission-revoke-when-running-jenkin-build/34088 did the trick for me. But, if I run an `adb reboot` then I'm stuck in the same place again...

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio go to Tools-> Android -> Restart Adb Server did it for me

Answer (score 1):

Add the following call to your command:

```
adb wait-for-device
```

example:

```
emulator -avd testAvd -no-boot-anim -no-snapshot-save -no-audio -no-window -gpu off -debug -all & adb wait-for-device
```

If you encounter an error saying `adb: command not found` you need to add paths into your bash/zsh config

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```